# ASP.NET + C# + jQuery: Click on a datalistItem which is a div then ItemCommand event will be fired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) datalist like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList_Trips" OnItemCommand="DataList_Trips_ItemCommand" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="divListTrips">
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Is there any chance when I click on the div with the class divListTrips, it will fire the event OnItemCommand?

Comment: What's your OnItemCommand event doing?  Postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using jQuery to call a page method, like in the example *[Using jQuery To Call ASP.NET Page Methods and Web Services](http://www.seoasp.net/post/2008/07/16/jQuery-To-Call-ASPNET-Page-Methods-and-Web-Services.aspx)*.

Instead of trying to coerce it to, call your ItemCommand handler.

Comment: Page method is always static. That is not a good option in my project. Thanks anyway. I think I should wrap all the text of the div inside a linkButton, that would be also a good idea!

Comment: that might *work*, but putting a DIV inside a A tag is not compliant.  If Page methods aren't a good option, you could achieve a similar behavior by passing a "action" querystring argument to your page.  In the OnLoad method, check the action argument and perform the desired behavior.  If there is not action argument, do the normal page load behavior.